# Deleting a ADOX database after opening and then closing

Tags: database, vb.net

I start up the application, select Database>New and save the file.  I then do the exact same thing, saving over the old file, but get the error:

The process cannot access the file `C:\test.mdb` because it is being used by another process.

That process is the application itself, and it did call for a `.Close()`.  This error only happens the second time through with the same file name.  It errors if I do a new test.mdb, test1.mdb, then test.mdb again, meaning it is still keeping them all open.

Here is the code:

```
Public catalog As New ADOX.Catalog
Public database As New ADODB.Connection

Private Sub mnuDatabaseNew_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles mnuDatabaseNew.Click
    If sfdDatabase.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        If database.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            database.Close()
            MsgBox("Closing old DB")
        End If
        If System.IO.File.Exists(sfdDatabase.FileName) Then System.IO.File.Delete(sfdDatabase.FileName)
        catalog.Create("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sfdDatabase.FileName)
        database.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sfdDatabase.FileName
        database.Open()
        catalog.ActiveConnection = database
    End If
End Sub
```